# the second condition of my login function is not working

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to set a login function which match the username and the password existing in my database However the first condition is working perfectly but not the second one

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['loginButton'])){
        //taking user input
        $username = $_POST['loginUsername'];
        $password = $_POST['loginPassword'];

        //Call of the login function through acccount variable
        $result = $account->login($username, $password);
        if($result == true){
            header('location:index.php');
        }
    }

?>

<?php
    class Account{

    ...

       public function login($un , $pw){
            $pw = md5($pw);
            $query = mysqli_query($this->con , "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$un' AND passwords = '$pw' ");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                array_push($this->errorArray , Constants::$loginFailed);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
?>

<?php
    class Constants{

        //Login constants
        public static $loginFailed = "Your username or password was incorrect";
    }
?>
```

i except it to return true so it will redirect me to the index page but actual input is false

Comment: Show your full code, where you create an instance of your class?

Comment: you might want to check you `login` function to see if it is actually returning `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Query will always return false, because it is not able to find the user with the given password, it is not the correct way to verify hashed password

```
 //this is where the problem is, do not verify password like this:
 $pw = md5($pw);
 $query = mysqli_query($this->con , "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username 
   = '$un' AND passwords = '$pw' ");
```

This is the correct way of verifying hashed passwords (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php):

```
if (password_verify($pw, $hash)) { //$hash password is from the DB
echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

So In your sql Query get the user with the given username first

```
$query = mysqli_query($this->con , "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$un'");
```

then Match the password from the DB with the current user given password `$pw` with `password_verify` function. so it will be something like this:

```
if($query){
  $data = mysqli_fetch_row($query); 

  if (password_verify($pw, $data['passwords'])) { //$data['password'] password is from the DB
    echo 'Password is valid!';
  } else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
  }
}
```